# Unable to call stored procedure from linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I am facing a strange issue. I have a linked server on ServerB for ServerA

Now, when I am calling a stored procedure from ServerB like

```
EXEC [ServerA].[Db].[dbo].[SpName] @Param1 @param2
```

I am getting error that

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SpName', database 'Db', schema 'dbo'.

But now when I am executing below query it is returning me result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [ServerA].[Db].[dbo].[tblName]
```

I don't know that why I am not able to execute stored procedure from ServerB. I am `Db_Owner` on both the server.

Screenshot of Linked server security

[image]

Linked server catalog

[image]

Comment: How is your linked server configured? Does it pass through credentials or does it use a fixed account (which may indeed not have execute permissions)?

Comment: You need the EXECUTE permssion to be assigned to the user you are executing with to the `SpName` stored procedure not to the table

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, it is on fixed account but which includes mine and service account.

Comment: If you log in to `ServerA` directly using exactly the account mapped in the dialog above, can you execute the stored procedure there? I know you said you're `db_owner`, but checking doesn't hurt... If that doesn't work, your problem's local security assignment. If that does work, something is amiss with account mapping.

Comment: Another possibility (less likely but possible) is that the link doesn't go where you think it goes. Try `exec('select @@servername') at [ServerA]` to be sure.

Comment: Does this work? SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([RemoteServer],DatabaseName.DatabaseOwner.StoredProcedureName)

Comment: @Sidux Yes, I tried that too.. same permission error

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I got my server name back ! I think linked server is working properly as I am also able to select Views and tables from it

Comment: Other things to check: `exec ('select user_name(), suser_name()') at [ServerA]` to verify you're mapping to the right user, and, of course, local execute permissions on `ServerA`.

Comment: I have also added linked server catalog snapshot . I am not sure but does it has a tree node for SP also?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Here is what I got 
**guest NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON**

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: then there's probably your problem. I don't think `guest` is supposed to have access to anything... so your local user isn't mapping to the remote user properly. If you are using Integrated Authentication, remove the impersonation for your account altogether (SQL Server will take care of it). If you're using SQL Server authentication, double check your configuration.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Absolutely correct ! I checked on guest account and I saw execute permission was denied. I unchecked it.. Now I am trying it again

Comment: Done.. I have fixed this Thanks alot !!!.. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've added an answer that covers all the points I raised in the comments. In this case, the solution was to grant access to the account that was actually accessing the linked server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a linked server query fails, the things to check are (in rough order of probability):

- Try logging in locally on the linked server to test access directly. If you have no local access, obviously you won't have it through the link either.
- Verify the correct credentials as used when accessing the linked server, and not another user you're not expecting. You can check this with `EXEC ('SELECT USER_NAME(), SUSER_NAME()') AT [Server]`; if the user name is not what you're expecting, check your linked server definition for the correct login mappings. If you can't access the server *at all* (any query fails), you have other problems (like Kerberos authentication issues if you're using integrated authentication).
- Perform a sanity check that you're accessing the correct server with `EXEC ('SELECT @@SERVERNAME') AT [Server]`. The network name of a linked server can be changed using `sp_setnetname`, so the name you use to a access the server isn't necessarily the machine name.
- If all else fails, dropping and recreating the linked server definition is always an option, but obviously this could disrupt production work.